# What is a word for "Reason to Leave"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

What is a word that means "Reason to leave"?

For example, if I said, "That was my reason to leave," how could I replace "reason to leave" with a single word?

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know there is no single word that means exactly *reason to leave*.  English doesn't have a single word for every concept imaginable; it often relies on combinations of words to describe specific ideas.  You could say, "That was my reason." and rely on context to supply the *what*.  I think a native speaker would typically just say, "That's why I left."

Answer (score 0):

When people have enough and willingly leave a situation, they might use an expression (not a single word) like

> This was ***the final/last straw***!

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/final-last-straw) defines this phrase as meaning

> the last in a series of unpleasant events that finally makes you feel that you cannot continue to accept a bad situation:
>
> - She's always been rude to me, but it was ***the last straw*** when she started insulting my mother.

Answer (score -2):

You could take in the context of leaving and say, "That was my **rationale**."

Comment: That doesn't really express it in one word. It's replacing *reason* with *rationale*.